# get_headers() not displaying Content-Encoding in PHP

Tags: php, apache, nginx, http-headers

I'm using the function **get_headers($url,1)** to get headers of the website http://www.sportsmalayalam.com/ The output is as follows. It doesn't have '**Content-Encoding**' But when I check the headers of same website through Google Chrome its showing content encoding as gzip.

On running: print_r(get_headers($url,1));

```
Array ( 
[0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
[1] => Date: Fri, 29 Apr 2016 10:35:20 GMT 
[2] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 
[3] => Connection: close 
[4] => Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d564038ff91bf8887430482dc8a8cf74b1461926119; expires=Sat, 29-Apr-17 10:35:19 GMT; path=/; domain=.sportsmalayalam.com; HttpOnly 
[5] => X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.16 
[6] => Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=empthbjqo968ak1a3cbaa6jr67; path=/ 
[7] => Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT 
[8] => Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0 
[9] => Pragma: no-cache 
[10] => Link: ; rel="https://api.w.org/" 
[11] => Link: ; rel=shortlink 
[12] => Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie 
[13] => Server: cloudflare-nginx 
[14] => CF-RAY: 29b21b47261e2fab-MAA 
)
```

From Google Chrome:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compare the **Request** headers. Chrome is probably sending an Accept-Encoding header that says that a gzipped response is OK while PHP is not. Consequently, the server is responding differently.

Comment: So i have to send request saying i can handle gzip?

Comment: Yes. Default is "do not compress", the client needs to *explicitly* request it.

Comment: How can I send that?

Comment: cURL is usually your best bet when you want to do anything more than the absolute basics when making HTTP requests.

Comment: Is this best way to get server response time of a website?

Comment: If you want to get better responses through gziping, look for some configuration on your web server (I see that is nginx).